# My wordpress website's menu and search bar is not working. I am using latest version of Neve Theme. What should I do now to fix this issue?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming, mobile-website

I made a wordpress based website [Mybgmi.com](https://mybgmi.com/) and my website's menu and search bar is not working in mobile devices. Can't understand how to fix this problem. I am just beginner. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Actually I tried a plugin to fix this problem. And before using this plug-in the menu and search bar is working fine every pages expect the homepage. Right now it is totally not working.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a plugin conflict , I disabled one of them it start working normally. For it was APM plugin for Neve theme , if you share more details i will be happy to assit